# Execute a query that does not include the specified aggregate function error message

Tags: ms-access

I have the following query that returns the error message `"you tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression"`

```
SELECT o.ea_guid as CLASSGUID, o.object_type as CLASSTYPE, o.name, COUNT(o.name) as NameCount
FROM t_object as o
GROUP BY o.name
HAVING (COUNT(o.name)>1)
```

Now if i include o.ea_guid & o.object_type in the `GROUP BY` clause, no results are returned

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COUNT(o.name) is an aggregate; the other attributes are not. If you want to show a non-aggregate, you have to put it in the GROUP BY clause. This will give you the count of rows for each unique combination of the three fields CLASSGUID, CLASSTYPE, and NAME.

```
SELECT 
    o.ea_guid as CLASSGUID, 
    o.object_type as CLASSTYPE,
    o.name as NAME, 
    COUNT(*) as NameCount
FROM 
    t_object as o
GROUP BY 
    o.ea_guid, 
    o.object_type,
    o.name

HAVING 
    (COUNT(*)>1)
```

This may not be what you have in mind ...

Comment: That doesn't work either. I get the message `"you tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'Name' as part of an aggregate function"`. If i include it in the `GROUP BY` clause, no results are returned either

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo - I made a quick change, but forgot to add `o.name` to the GROUP BY clause.  I've now added it in above. Do you see why that causes the error?

Answer (score 0):

The query has two errors:

```
o.ea_guid as CLASSGUID, o.object_type as CLASSTYPE
```

Mean that the result will be referenced to particular artefact in Enterprise Architect model, so you can NOT use it in agregation query in Enterprise Architect. Use:

```
SELECT o.name, COUNT(o.name) as NameCount
FROM t_object as o
GROUP BY o.name
HAVING (COUNT(o.name)>1)
```

or all selected atributes should be in GROUP BY clause:

```
SELECT o.ea_guid as CLASSGUID, o.object_type as CLASSTYPE, o.name, COUNT(o.name) as NameCount
FROM t_object as o
GROUP BY o.ea_guid , o.object_type , o.name
HAVING (COUNT(o.name)>1)
```

which seems stupid in this case